Weird C Syntax for implementing a List
I am programming on the NXP RT1170 chip using their SDK (Free Scale Library). While working with their CMOS Sensor Interface (CSI) driver, I encountered an unusual syntax that I couldn't understand, and I haven't seen it used elsewhere.
The syntax appears to be used for implementing some kind of linked list mechanism for managing frame buffer addresses. Here’s the relevant code snippet:
static uint32_t CSI_TransferGetEmptyBuffer(csi_handle_t *handle)
{
    pvoid_to_u32_t buf;

    buf.pvoid = handle->emptyBuffer;
    handle->emptyBufferCnt--;
    handle->emptyBuffer = *(void **)(buf.pvoid);

    return buf.u32;
}

static void CSI_TransferPutEmptyBuffer(csi_handle_t *handle, uint32_t buffer)
{
    pvoid_to_u32_t buf;
    buf.u32 = buffer;

    *(void **)(buf.pvoid) = handle->emptyBuffer;
    handle->emptyBuffer   = buf.pvoid;
    handle->emptyBufferCnt++;
}

Here are the structure definitions used in these functions:
typedef union pvoid_to_u32
{
    void *pvoid;
    uint32_t u32;
} pvoid_to_u32_t;


typedef struct _csi_handle
{
    uint32_t frameBufferQueue[CSI_DRIVER_ACTUAL_QUEUE_SIZE]; /*!< Frame buffer queue. */

    volatile uint8_t queueWriteIdx;  /*!< Pointer to save incoming item. */
    volatile uint8_t queueReadIdx;   /*!< Pointer to read out the item. */
    void *volatile emptyBuffer;      /*!< Pointer to maintain the empty frame buffers. */
    volatile uint8_t emptyBufferCnt; /*!< Empty frame buffers count. */

    volatile uint8_t activeBufferNum; /*!< How many frame buffers are in progres currently. */

    volatile bool transferStarted; /*!< User has called @ref CSI_TransferStart to start frame receiving. */

    csi_transfer_callback_t callback; /*!< Callback function. */
    void *userData;                   /*!< CSI callback function parameter.*/
}csi_handle_t;

The functions are used, as their names suggest, to add and retrieve frame buffer addresses from a list of empty buffers. Specifically:

CSI_TransferPutEmptyBuffer : Adds a buffer address to the list.
CSI_TransferGetEmptyBuffer : Retrieves a buffer address from the list.

The Syntax in Question:
The part I find unusual is this:
*(void **)(buf.pvoid) = handle->emptyBuffer;
handle->emptyBuffer = *(void **)(buf.pvoid);

It appears to be manipulating a linked list by using void * and void ** to link and unlink buffer addresses. The union pvoid_to_u32_t is used to seamlessly cast between pointers (void *) and integers (uint32_t).
Does anyone have insight into this syntax or a better understanding of what is happening here? Is this a common technique in low-level programming or unique to this implementation?

This code manages blocks of memory being allocated and freed from other use and uses void * to link free blocks into a list and uses void ** to assist that. It uses uint32_t as a container for pointer values. Neither of these is unusual. While they appear together in this code, they are separate, not entangled.
CSI_TransferPutEmptyBuffer is given a handle that points to a structure used to help manage memory and a uint32_t that provides the address of a buffer that is being released. (It is no longer needed to hold data and can be added to a list of buffers available for reallocation.) It is given the address in the form of a uint32_t and uses the union to reinterpret this uint32_t as a void *. (This relies on implementation-specific features, including that pointers are 32 bits, so it is not fully portable C code.)
Given that void *, now in buf.pvoid, *(void **)(buf.pvoid) = … says to store a void * in that memory. In detail, buf.pvoid is a pointer to some memory of unknown type, so void ** says to convert it to a pointer to void *, and then *(void **)(buf.pvoid) = … says to store something there. The value stored there is the address of the currently first item on the list, the value in handle->emptyBuffer.
After that, handle->emptyBuffer   = buf.pvoid; sets the newly released buffer to be the new first item on the list. This is ordinary linked-list code.
In CSI_TransferGetEmptyBuffer, buf.pvoid = handle->emptyBuffer; gets the address of the first list item and stores it in buf.pvoid to be reinterpreted later. Then handle->emptyBuffer = *(void **)(buf.pvoid); gets the pointer (to the next available buffer) that was stored in the buffer and makes it the new first item on the list. After that, return buf.u32; reinterprets the void * as a uint32_t.
The reason that uint32_t is used to hold pointers is not visible in this code; it is for some reason not shown. It is not related to the void ** conversions; those could be done without using uint32_t.
